# Is there a way to install node_modules globally when creating ember app using ember-cli?

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Every time I generate a new ember app using the ember-cli

```
ember new my-app
```

It will have 177MB `node_modules` inside `my-app` folder.
Is there a way to just install this node_modules globally and not have it on every ember project?

Note: I see you can pass `--skip-npm`, but how do I install the node_modules globally when I skip npm?

Answer (score 1):

After asking around on ember forum, the answer is no.

http://discuss.emberjs.com/t/does-using-ember-cli-always-have-to-install-177mb-node-modules-on-every-project/7449

But you can still work around it by creating new project using `--skip-npm` option and then symlink the node_modules directory. Assuming that you want to use the same version of node_modules installed by ember-cli on every project.

Comment: Hopefully things will improve with the change to yarn. https://github.com/ember-cli/rfcs/pull/88

Answer (score 0):

yarn caches packages so I would recommend upgrading to ember 2.11 and switching to yarn. 
Download and install yarn from https://yarnpkg.com/
To migrate an existing project type `yarn` on its own.
Afterwards use `yarn install` the same as you would with npm.

See https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/migrating-from-npm/ for more details.

At some point yarn is probably going to be the only option for ember (https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/6341#issuecomment-265604502) so you might as well switch now. It's pretty painless!